# facebook connect: read Page stream without being logged in

Tags: .net, facebook

I'm using the facebook developer's toolkit for a facebook connect website. The website posts content to the stream for a page - which I have working fine.

I'd like to also get the stream from the page to show users who visit the website - regardless if they are logged in to facebook or not. Facebook provides a handy fan box (fbml) for this, but the big problem here is that it only shows the stream for items posted by the page, not items posted by fans. I of course need to show content posted by fans and well as the page.

So, I've been going around in circles trying to figure out how to do this, with no luck. It seems I need to grant read_stream permissions to my application, not to a specific user. I'm not sure where / how I go about doing this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict.Add("method", "facebook.stream.get")
Utilities.AddOptionalParameter(dict, "viewer_id", userIdToImpersonate)
Utilities.AddList(dict, "source_ids", pageIds)

Dim fbSession As New ConnectSession(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Facebook_Key"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Facebook_Secret"))
Dim api As New Facebook.Rest.Api(fbSession)
Dim resp As stream_get_response = api.SendRequest(Of stream_get_response)(dict, True)
```

I sorted this out using Reflector on the Facebook Developers Toolkit api. The Facebook.Rest.Stream.Get method should have worked, but was throwing exceptions, so I used this base call instead.